# Ocultar um radio button quando clicar em outro radio button

Tags: php, javascript, radiobutton

Bom dia pessoal, estou com uma dúvida nos radio button, não faço ideia do que fazer.. sou um pouco novo no php / javascript e queria entender como posso fazer isso funcionar.
Eu tenho uma grade de cursos, nessa grade preciso que o aluno preencha sua preferência com 5 tópicos, então o que eu fiz, criei uma div onde separa os radio buttons lado a lado, ficando assim.

(3) Web Design
(5) Montagem e manutenção
(4) Rotinas de escritório
(2) Hotelaria
(1) Atendimento ao cliente

Basicamente preciso que o usuário clique em qual ele prefere de 1 a 5, como acho que o modo mais fácil de exibir isso e facilitar seria com radio button, gostaria que assim, se o usuário clicar em Web Design com a opção 1, o campo Web Design oculte para que não clique mais e decida as próximas sequencialmente.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Se você quer permitir várias seleções, não deve usar o `Radio Button` pois a ideia dele é que se escolha apenas uma.
Sugiro que use `Checkboxes` para isso. Também sugiro que não *esconda* o elemento, mas `desabilite-o`. Lembre-se que uma vez desabilitado, o usuário não irá conseguir desmarcar, com isso, você precisa garantir alguma maneira de recomeçar a seleção.

Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```js
checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll(".ck-preferencias");
prioridades = document.getElementById("prioridades");
btLimpar = document.getElementById("limpar");

checkboxes.forEach(function(checkbox){
  checkbox.addEventListener('click', function(){
    pai = checkbox.closest("li");
    escolhido = document.createElement("li");
    escolhido.name="prioridades[]";
    escolhido.innerHTML = pai.innerText;
    checkbox.disabled = true;
    checkbox.checked = false;
    prioridades.appendChild(escolhido);
  });
});

btLimpar.addEventListener('click', function(){
  prioridades.innerHTML = "";  
  checkboxes.forEach(function(checkbox){
    checkbox.disabled = false;
  });
});
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><input class="ck-preferencias" type="checkbox" value="web-design" />Web design</li>
  <li><input class="ck-preferencias" type="checkbox" value="manutencao" />Manutenção</li>
  <li><input class="ck-preferencias" type="checkbox" value="rotinas" />Rotinas de Escritório</li>
  <li><input class="ck-preferencias" type="checkbox" value="hotelaria" />Hotelaria</li>
  <li><input class="ck-preferencias" type="checkbox" value="atendimento" />Atendimento ao cliente</li>
</ul>

<ol id="prioridades">
</ol>

<button id="limpar">Limpar seleção</button>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado! Isso vai ajudar muito, estava a um bom tempo sem saber como prosseguir '-', obrigado mesmo pela força!

Comment: Disponha, estamos aqui para ajudar.

Comment: Amigo aqui funciona perfeitamente, porém por que quando encaminho o mesmo código pro Atom e executo no meu sistema não funciona? desculpe sou meio leigo em programação ainda